# How do I generate SECRET_KEY in django and postgresql database for a .env file?

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, secret-key

A bit confusing to me is I am working on a project with a previously generated key - like so: `SECRET_KEY='1x8n9Xj4UNw8T2PgIiaircPBcZ5z9u0TTBivRbeTMbbRsiNM1VUjWlkP1mDZy8o11csfee*^5jvpGsH41VYVUAx8jE110ashdjkrkGBIjJRQ1SxU8irV6mcNz-3rQ1RDWiDv1WqmSfVtUX4kYymodEEZkeKNH4mQUlHsqdVX2ZAJ4BQaYmQOzKls'`

but its longer that the one I generated which is more like so:

```
SECRET_KEY='te1we2*&v_&!9p1jhl7-aa@z$mlrb#v=2%xuyt%h([(ew@3z0^'
```

using this command

```
python manage.py shell -c 'from django.core.management import utils; print(utils.get_random_secret_key())'
```

And in what instances would the KEY not be enclosed with quotes('') in the .env file.

I know the procedure involved in securing the secrets, my confusion comes with the structure of the first SECRET_KEY which makes me think am doing something the wrong way.

Comment: Different types of generation 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67501385/11297170

Comment: How can I use these different hashing methods to generate keys?

Comment: Use length as long as you want
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68085559/11297170